# How to speedup h.265 a video by 1000x without reencoding

Tags: ffmpeg, h.265

I am looking for a way to speedup a huge videofile (dashcam video) in order to be able to browse through quickly. Is it possible to only copy keyframes and also change frame rate to 120fps? I found several recommendations for ffmpeg on google but nothing worked.

cheers
Timo

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the video stream to pure raw data file and then remux it with a new framerate.

For example, in case of h265 codec, these two commands should work for you:

```
ffmpeg -discard nokey -i input.mp4 -c copy -bsf hevc_mp4toannexb -f hevc output.h265
ffmpeg -r 120 -i output.h265 -c copy output.mp4
```

Comment: Can he just do this? `ffmpeg -r 120 -i input.mp4 -c copy output.mp4`

Comment: @kesh Whenever I try to use your way it does not work for me - it seems that `-r X` option works only in case where the framerate of the input is not defined.

Comment: Huh, interesting. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Don't you need `-skip_frame nokey` input option to extract key frames only? [Source](https://superuser.com/questions/669716)

Comment: @kesh: Thanks for this, I forgot about this "requirement". I added `-discard nokey` as I found this in the current ffmpeg documentation: `-discard (input)` - "*allows discarding specific streams or frames from streams*".

Comment: -discard nokey or -skip_frame nokey seems not to work for h.265 input files. I have h.256 in a mkv.  But also h.256 in mp4 does not work.

Comment: @Timo: I've just tested the command with input.mkv/h265 and it did not work, but after the conversion of this file to input.mp4/h265 (`ffmpeg -i input.mkv -c copy input.mp4`) it worked with no problem.

Comment: @Timo: Maybe your input stream has only/mostly keyframes or you are using some older ffmpeg version? Did you check the input with ffprobe? Also tell us the version of your ffmpeg.

Comment: ffmpeg version 4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
ffprobe version 4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1 Copyright (c) 2007-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2)
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'cam_2022-02-16_18-08-08.mkv':
  Metadata:
    title           : Stream
    ENCODER         : Lavf58.29.100
  Duration: 00:30:00.06, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1940 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: hevc (Main), yuvj420p(pc), 2560x1440, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1k tbn, 25 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      DURATION        : 00:30:00.029000000

Comment: @Timo: Have you checked the presence of keyframes with ffprobe? As I said: maybe every frame in your file is a keyframe?

Comment: Ok, good tip. Keyframes are like this:
key_frame=0
key_frame=1
key_frame=0
key_frame=0
key_frame=1
key_frame=0
key_frame=1
key_frame=0
key_frame=0
key_frame=1
...

Comment: I guess so there is no easy way without reencoding. I have another approach here. This is on the playback side.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71179413/how-to-browse-through-a-very-very-long-video-quickly

Comment: @Timo: It seems that every second or third frame in your file is a keyframe and `-discard nokey` will help only a little. Yes, you will probably need to reencode with something like this: `ffmpeg -i input.mkv -vf "select=not(mod(n\,<x>)),setpts=N/<input framerate>/TB" output.mp4` to simply select every <x>th frame.