# How to browse through a very very long video quickly

Tags: ffmpeg, h.265

I have several month of h.265 video from a security cam. I like to look through quickly.
Problem: All videoplayers are only able to speed up up to 100x. Also it's 4k. So speedup is also limited by CPU power. I need 1000x speedup or more. So I need a player which is capable looking only on keyframes (to speed up processing) and also process only every x keyframe to make it really fast. This should work in a player. I don't want to reencode.

Any Ideas

cheers
Timo

Comment: Please don't post essentially the same question twice https://stackoverflow.com/q/71178454/2836621 It wastes people's time.

Comment: This one is about playback. The other one is about converting the file.

Comment: If I open the file on my Samsung S21 with default VideoPlayer and scroll through the video very fast (finger on navigationbar swiping slowly to the right) the video plays very fast an very smooth (120fps). This is what I want to have. But I need this on a WindowsApplication and without the need to manuelly scroll.